# Two polynomials having the same roots are identical

Tags: polynomials, roots

The polynomials $f$ and $g$ have same roots(no repeated roots) and $\{x : f(x) = 2015\} = \{x : g(x) = 2015\}$ = S. Here S is non-empty. Show that $f = g$.

Here $x$ is a complex number. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: The way this question is stated makes little sense to me.

Comment: Allow me to clear your confusion. Please tell me where do you find the ambiguity?

Comment: In light of the answer below I think it was just notation. Since polynomials with the same roots are equal up to a constant I was a little buffaloed.

Comment: What if f has a repeated root where g has a single root? For example, $g(x) = 2015x$ and $f(x) = 2015x^3$.

Comment: You are totally correct. And I think if that happens we can't say anything about f and g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be $n+1$ roots of each $f$ and $g$ and let these roots be $a_{0},a_{1},...,a_{n}$

Hence,

$f(x)=A[\prod_{r=0}^{n}(x-a_{0})]$

$g(x)=B[\prod_{r=0}^{n}(x-a_{0})]$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Since there exists an $x_{0}$ such that $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})=2015$,

we deduce that:

$A[\prod_{r=0}^{n}(x_{0}-a_{0})]=2015=B[\prod_{r=0}^{n}(x_{0}-a_{0})]$

it follows that,

$A=B$, thus $f$ and $g$ are identical.

Comment: What about the case where both sets in the OP are empty? (i.e. there is no $x_0$ with that property)

Comment: I think the question was asked with horrible (incorrect) notation. I think they mean that there exists an $x_{0}$ such that $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})=2015$. If the sets in question are empty, there is nothing else we can say about these function. They may or may not be identical.

Comment: You are right. I should had mentioned that those sets were non-empty.